# How to configure SELinux to print date and time in each entry in audit log?

Tags: centos, selinux

I'm using CentOS 5.5 and by default my `/var/log/audit/audit.log` looks like this:

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1331897657.359:8435): user pid=15610 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='PAM: authentication acct="?" : exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" (hostname=c165-130.i02-2.onvol.net, addr=213.165.165.130, terminal=ssh res=failed)'
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1331897657.360:8436): user pid=15610 uid=0 auid=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='acct="oracle": exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" (hostname=?, addr=213.165.165.130, terminal=sshd res=failed)'
```

to be exact, log entries are written without timestamp It makes it more difficult to troubleshoot. There is a man page available

```
 man auditd.conf
```

but all it says in this subject is:

```
log_format
     The log format describes how the information should be stored on
     disk.  There  are  2 options: raw and nolog.  If set to RAW, the
     audit records will be stored in a format exactly as  the  kernel
     sends it. If this option is set to NOLOG then all audit informa-
     tion is discarded instead of writing to disk. This mode does not
     affect data sent to the audit event dispatcher.
```

How do I configure it to print date/time on the beginning of every entry ?

Answer (score 4):

While there aren't any options you can set to make auditd log with a human-parseable date format, if you use the 'ausearch' command to search your audit log, there is an `-i` option which produces human-readable (well, perhaps slightly more human readable) output.

For example, if I ran `ausearch -ts today` on my newly-booted system, I see:

```
# ausearch -ts today
----
time->Mon Mar 19 23:07:00 2012
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(1332212820.421:3834): auditd start, ver=2.1.3 format=raw kernel=3.2.10-3.fc16.x86_64 auid=4294967295 pid=6438 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=success
```

But if I run `ausearch -ts today -i`, I see:

```
# ausearch -ts today -i
----
type=DAEMON_START msg=audit(03/19/2012 23:07:00.421:3834) : auditd start, ver=2.1.3 format=raw kernel=3.2.10-3.fc16.x86_64 auid=unset pid=6438 subj=system_u:system_r:auditd_t:s0 res=success
```

Does that work for you?  `ausearch` is probably what you'll be using to look at audit records anyway.  `-i` also does stuff like uid->username lookups and other resolutions.
**EDIT**: You can see from the above that I'm running Fedora 16, but the same `ausearch -i` applies to RHEL5.

Answer (score 3):

That long number at the beginning is a timestamp: it's seconds since the epoch. A few moments ago, I got:

```
[0 1128 18:09:57] ~ % date +%s; date
1331917801
Fri Mar 16 18:10:01 CET 2012
```

To convert the number into something more readable, try

```
[0 1133 18:12:41] ~ % date -d @1331897657
Fri Mar 16 12:34:17 CET 2012
```

(So apparently, you'll need "usual `sed` tricks" to cut off the sub-second parts.)

I don't have a SE-enabled machine handy, but maybe `sealert -a` also parses the timestamps into something human-readable?

Comment: In fact, `sealert` may be very powerfull tool, but it's now what I've exactly looked for. And a little digression here: `sealert` generates output that looks like it's been conformed to Windows Server audit, don't You think ?

Answer (score 3):

```
ausearch -i
```

From help:

```
-i,--interpret    Interpret results to be human readable
```

that't the correct answear as **jsbillings** wrote.

No need to run tail -f !

P.S.
Darn stack points ! That's why I couldn't comment or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems, there is no option to change the format in which `auditd` writes it's log entries, I have written the following bash script, that converts `audit.log`.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

lines=(`tail -n 20 /var/log/audit/audit.log`)

for olin in ${lines[*]}; do
    datt=`echo $olin | perl -nle '/msg=audit\(([0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{3}):/  && print "$1"'`
    date_human_readable=`date -d @$datt +%Y-%m-%d\ %k:%M:%S`
    echo ${date_human_readable}"    "${olin}
done
```

It inserts event date before every entry and prints result on the screen. The date is extracted from entry itself (`msg=audit(...`) and converted from UNIX timestamp to human readable format.

Of course You can use `cat` instead of `tail`.

Please correct me if You see any possible way to improve / simplify that script.

Answer (score -1):

```
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | ausearch -i
```